# reading text from between a specific html div with vb

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I'm working on a program that reads a web page and pops up a messagebox
whenever there is an update to the page. now my goal is to log into the website
and display the username of the logged in account in my program

how can i get the text from within the welcome_user div?
also how can i check to see if the welcome_user div is on the page and if not
log into the website(i know how to do the log in part)

Example of the Html:

```
<div id="usrpnl" style="float:right;">
     <div class="frm_login" style="text-align:right;">
          <div class="welcome_user"><b>Welcome (Username here)!</b></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how you access the web page? WebBrowser, WebRequest...

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegularExpression to match the username:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '~~~ Sample HTML
        Dim strHtml As String = "<div id=""usrpnl"" style=""float:right;"">" & _
                                    "<div class=""frm_login"" style=""text-align:right;"">" & _
                                        "<div class=""welcome_user""><b>Welcome Akhilesh!</b></div>" & _
                                    "</div>" & _
                                "</div>"

        '~~~ Regular Expression to match the username from the HTML
        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(strHtml, "Welcome\s(.*)!", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        If m.Success Then   '~~~ if found...
            Dim strUsername As String = m.Groups(1).Value   '~~~ ...gets the matched username
            MessageBox.Show(strUsername)    '~~~ display it
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Username not found !") '~~~ not found !
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this will help. Wish you good luck.